# Image cannot resize using PHP

Tags: php, laravel, image-processing, gd2

I'm trying to resize an image that I copy from Flickr. But it seems I'm getting the original size itself. Here is my code:

```php
$img = Input::get('FlickrUrl');
$filename = gmdate('Ymdhis', time());
copy($img, $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/upload/'.$filename.'.jpeg');
$newImg = '/upload/'.$filename.'.jpeg';
list($CurWidth, $CurHeight) = getimagesize($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].$newImg);

$width = $CurWidth;
$height = $CurHeight;
$image_ratio = $CurWidth / $CurHeight;

//resize image according to container
$container_width = 300;
$container_height = 475;

if($CurWidth > $container_width)
{
    $CurWidth = $container_width;
    $CurHeight = $CurWidth / $image_ratio;
}
if($CurHeight > $container_height)
{
    $CurHeight = $container_height;
    $CurWidth = $CurHeight * $image_ratio;
}

if($CurWidth < $container_width)
{
    $CurWidth = $container_width;
    $CurHeight = $CurWidth / $image_ratio;
}
if($CurHeight < $container_height){
    $CurHeight = $container_height;
    $CurWidth = $CurHeight * $image_ratio;
}

$img_orginal = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/upload/'.$filename.'.jpeg';
$img_org = ImageCreateFromJPEG($img_orginal);
$NewCanves  = imagecreatetruecolor($CurWidth, $CurHeight);
imagecopyresized($NewCanves, $img_org, 0, 0, 0, 0, $CurWidth, $CurHeight, $width, $height);
$finalImg = '/upload/'.$filename.'.jpeg';


return Response::json(["success"=>"true", "images"=>$finalImg, "width"=>$CurWidth, "height"=>$CurHeight]);
```

First I copy the Image from the URL, saves it in my server and then trying to resize it. 
Can't understand whats wrong with this code.

Comment: You would much help potential answers by reducing your code to its minimum to reproduce your issue. In the process you could even find that you can solve your issue yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you don't save your file. After:

```
imagecopyresized($NewCanves, $img_org, 0, 0, 0, 0, $CurWidth, $CurHeight, $width, $height);
$finalImg = '/upload/'.$filename.'.jpeg'
```

you should add:

```
imagejpeg($NewCanves, $finalImg);
```

to save it in filesystem

Comment: Its still giving me the same size.

Answer (score 1):

Try [intervention/image](http://image.intervention.io/) package with great [Laravel integration](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation#laravel):

```php
// open an image file
$img = Image::make('FlickrUrl');

// now you are able to resize the instance
$img->resize($container_width, $container_height);

// finally we save the image as a new file
$img->save('/upload/'.$filename.'.jpeg');
```

Comment: Yeah I used it :) Thanks for the suggestion.